# subquery inside orWhere in laravel

Tags: laravel

I need assistance to build up the query like below in laravel:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t 
WHERE t.a = 1 
  OR (t.a=0 
    AND t.id IN (
      SELECT o.a_id 
      FROM other_table o 
      WHERE o.x > 3
    )
  );
```

Comment: You can use Laravel DB Raw Expressions, read docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Answer (score 2):

You could try to build your exact current query, and in fact it might even be the most efficient to write it.  But, if we rephrase your query using a left join, it becomes somewhat easier to express in Laravel code.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table t
LEFT JOIN other_table o
    ON t.id = o.a_id AND o.x > 3
WHERE
    t.a = 1 OR
    (t.a = 0 AND o.a_id IS NOT NULL);
```

This would translate to the following Laravel code:

```
$result = DB::table('your_table t')
    ->leftJoin('other_table o', function($join) {
        $join->on('t.id', '=', 'o.a_id');
        $join->on('o.x', '>', '3');
    })
    ->where('t.a', '=', '1')
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
        return $query->where('t.a', '=', '0')
            ->whereNotNull('o.a_id')
        })
    ->get();
```